# Returning data by looking at a start value from one column and only if a certain value was conducted first

Tags: sql, db2

I hope someone can help me with this issue.

I have the following code :

```
WITH CTE AS ( SELECT SITEID, NIINs, TRX_DT
FROM
(SELECT A.SITEID, max(B.TRX_DT) as TRX_DT,A.NIINs
FROM KCA0001.TRANS A LEFT OUTER JOIN DDCNENVR.ATR B ON B.SITE_ID = A.SITEID AND
B.NIIN = A.NIINs AND(B.TRX_DT BETWEEN '2018225' AND '2018273') AND B.DOC_ID IN ('D8A','D9A')
WHERE A.SITEID = 'HECN'
Group by A.SITEID, A.NIINs, B.MED_STA_CD

 UNION

SELECT A.SITEID, max(B.TRX_DT) as TRX_DT,  A.NIINs
FROM KCA0001.TRANS A LEFT OUTER JOIN DDDEENVR.ATR B ON B.SITE_ID = A.SITEID AND
B.NIIN = A.NIINs AND(B.TRX_DT BETWEEN '2018225' AND '2018273') AND B.DOC_ID IN ('D8A','D9A')
WHERE A.SITEID = 'EGDE'
Group by A.SITEID, A.NIINs, B.MED_STA_CD

UNION

SELECT A.SITEID, max(B.TRX_DT) as TRX_DT, A.NIINs
FROM KCA0001.TRANS A LEFT OUTER JOIN DDWGENVR.ATR B ON B.SITE_ID = A.SITEID AND
B.NIIN = A.NIINs AND(B.TRX_DT BETWEEN '2018225' AND '2018273') AND B.DOC_ID IN ('D8A','D9A')
WHERE A.SITEID = 'HEWG'
Group by A.SITEID, A.NIINs, B.MED_STA_CD))

SELECT A.SITEID AS SITE_ID,  B.TRX_DT, B.SEQ_TIME, B.DOC_ID, B.RIC, B.MED_STA_CD, B.FSC, A.NIINS AS NIIN, B.UI, B.ADJ_QTY, B.DOCNO, B.MULT_USE_45_53, B.DISTR_CD, B.PROJ_CD, B.MULT_USE_60_66, B.DEPOT_RIC, B.O_P_CD, B.COND_CD, B.MGT_CD, B.JULN_DAY, B.MULT_USE_76_80, B.OPN_BAL_SEG, B.MAND_RSCH_CD, B.CAUSE_DOC_ID, B.RCN,B.OPNS_CTL_NO, B.CIIC, B.UPRICE, B.MGR_RIC, B.PRGM_ID, A.TRX_DT AS START_DT
FROM CTE A
LEFT OUTER JOIN  DDDEENVR.ATR B ON A.NIINs = b.NIIN AND A.SITEID = B.SITE_ID AND B.TRX_DT >= A.TRX_DT 
WHERE CTE.SITEID = 'EGDE'
```

My employer has requested that i create a query that will pull data depending on a few criteria. The above code uses CTE to create a table with the most recent date of a D8A or D9A(DOC_ID column).

Table KCA0001.Trans(Table 1) is joined with table DDCNENVR.ATR (Table 2) on SITE_ID(Column 1), NIIN (Column 2), and DOC ID (Column 3) IN (D8A, D9A). 
WHICH will give me a value in the column TRX_DT such as 2018100

What i want to do is use that 2018100 value that is associated with the Site_ID(Column 1) and NIIN( Column 2) and use it as a start date but only if a D8A or D9A under DOC_ID has been completed first.

So say there is a row with :

```
SITE_ID   NIIN     DOC_ID   TRX_DT   START_DT
 NY       1111      D8A     2018100   2018100
 NY       1111      DJZ     2018101   2018100
 PA       1112      D9A     2018100   2018100
 PA       1112      DJZ     2018101   2018100
 VA       1113      BCA     2018101   2018100
 VA       1113      DJZ     2018102   2018100
```

NY AND PA are good however VA should not have been returned due to not having a D8A or D9A done first.

Im still very new to SQL so i understand if the code provided is not the greatest. Please let me know if i can clarify better.

Comment: give an example of data in your 2 tables and an example of expected result please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly Me, The code is actually doing what i wanted it to do all i needed was:

```
ORDER BY 1 ASC, 8 ASC, 2 ASC, 3 ASC, 4 ASC, 31 ASC
```

at the end and it organized my data.